# can't change text of a

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `javascript` function that creates a lot of panels using an `ajax` request. After the request gives me a valid `json`, I populate all the widgets like this:

```
function createAllWidgets() {
    var funcid = 'get_widget_info';
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'functions/call_functions.php',
        data: {
            funcid: funcid
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(myData) {

        if (myData == null) {
            alert('something went worng');
        } else {
          var html = '';
          for (var i=0;i<myData.length;i++) {
                html += '<h3 id="' + myData[i].widget_abb_upper + '-EUR" class="text-primary counter m-t-10">0</h3>'
                     +  '<h3 id="' + myData[i].widget_abb_upper + '-USD" class="text-primary counter m-t-10">0</h3>';
            }
            $('#widgets').html(html);
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {alert('something went worng');}); 

}
```

I have another function that changes the `.text()` of some of the `div` objects within the widget:

```
function setWidget(priceUSD, priceEUR, widget) {
    $('#' + widget + '-EUR').text(priceEUR);
    $('#' + widget + '-USD').text(priceUSD);
}
```

For some reason the `id` can not be found/used when populated with `ajax`. When the widget is not created with ajax (but in static `html`) it does work..

**EDIT:**
I made a `callback` in the function that generates the widgets:

```
function createAllWidgets(callback) {
    var funcid = 'get_widget_info';
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'functions/call_functions.php',
        data: {
            funcid: funcid
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(myData) {

        if (myData == null) {
            alert('something went worng');
        } else {
          var html = '';
          for (var i=0;i<myData.length;i++) {
                html += '<h3 id="' + myData[i].widget_abb_upper + '-EUR" class="text-primary counter m-t-10">0</h3>'
                     +  '<h3 id="' + myData[i].widget_abb_upper + '-USD" class="text-primary counter m-t-10">0</h3>';
            }
            $('#widgets').html(html);
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {alert('something went worng');}); 

}
```

Then I made a new function to call the above two functions:

```
function initStart() {
    createAllWidgets(function() {
        setWidget(1,1,'widget1');
    });
}
```

But this still doesn't work..

Comment: When does `setWidget` run?  Since you are generating these as a result of an async call, it seems you are trying to operate on divs that aren't there yet.

Comment: Are you sure that the `widget` string passed to `setWidget()` is correct. Remember it will be case sensitive.

Comment: @jmargolisvt: I edited my post and made a callback. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ajax** is asynchronous, meaning that the **done** handler will be called after the function returns. Your solution of adding a callback doesn't work because you haven't called it.

If you still want to use a callback, add this:

```
$('#widgets').html(html); // This is yours
callback();               // <- Add this
```

A better way, is to use the jqXHR events - like done:

```
function initStart() {
    createAllWidgets().done(function() {
        setWidget(1,1,'widget1');
    });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. This indeed did the trick. I still used the `callback`. Can you explain why you prefer the `jqXHR` over the `callback` method?

Comment: I like Promises better than callbacks. the jqXHR object is a wrapper around XMLHttpRequest and it behaves as a promise - hence the `done()` method. you can read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: OK. Will take this into account!